# MongoDB Date query JAVA

Tags: java, mongodb

Im trying to do a query to get all the values from my DB wich each have a date. One example:

```
leadTime: [
    {
      date: ISODate("2014-03-19T23:00:00Z"),
      value: 25.8
    },
    {
      date: ISODate("2014-03-20T23:00:00Z"),
      value: 31.299999999999997
    },
    {
      date: ISODate("2014-03-21T23:00:00Z"),
      value: 34.4
    }
]
enter code here
```

My code is:

```
DBObject query=new BasicDBObject("group",group);
DBObject serieData= col.findOne(query,new BasicDBObject(serie, 1));
if (serieData != null) {
List<DBObject> data = (List<DBObject>) serieData.get(serie);
for (DBObject item : data) {
    result.add(new HistoryData((Date) item.get("date"),(Double) item.get("value")));
}
```

Now I want to get the values that the date is bigger than a date that I pass by parameter. The query I did is this:

```
DBObject query=new BasicDBObject("group",group)
        .append("date", new BasicDBObject("$gte", parameterDate))
        ;
```

But I always receive the result empty, can you help me? sorry for my english and than

Comment: Group is an Integer that indicates the team on which I want to do the query.

Comment: If I understand it well leadTime is an embedded document of your documents of the collection col that have a field group. Am I right ? Can you post a whole document ?

Comment: Sorry, I've notice I read wrong your question. group is a String, not an Integer. The value of group is LeadTime and it has the fields value and date. the whole document is so big, thats why I have to do the date query. Thanks a lot for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `leadTime` is a field in your documents, your query has to look like this

```
DBObject query=new BasicDBObject("group",group)
    .append("leadTime.date", new BasicDBObject("$gte", parameterDate))
    ;
```

The way you did it, MongoDB would have searched for a date field in your document root:

```
{ _id: "Foo",
  date: ISODate("2014-03-19T23:00:00Z"),
  [...]
}
```

Queries in MongoDB don't make a difference if the queried field is a single value or an array, so using the dot notation on a field which holds an array of subdocuments is perfectly valid.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I tried that but I receive an empty result.

Comment: Please add a complete document to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not possible with a simple query.
But if you still want to do it in mongodb you need to use the aggregation framework, with something like that :

```
db.<col_name>.aggregate( [ { $unwind : "$group" }, { $match : {'group.date': { $gte : parameterDate } } ] )
```

this a js command, but you should be able to translate it easly in Java Driver (you can also add a $project operation to just return needed fields).